# Changing the xpath by taking elements from a list

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

I was doing web scraping and trying to scrape using xpath and selenium. The xpath can be changed by just changing which i have stored in a list. I wanted to create a loop which can automatically change the xpath and find the contents. I tried this, but somewhere i am going wrong.

```
packages= ["EVENINGS_AND_WEEKEND_EXTRA", "ANYTIME_EXTRA"]

for i in packages:
    name= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productButtonControls_ST_"+i]/label')
    print name.text
```

Instead of "EVENINGS_AND_WEEKEND_EXTRA", i want different elements in the list packages.

```
#this is the required xpath which needs to be altered
    //*[@id="productButtonControls_ST_EVENINGS_AND_WEEKEND_EXTRA"]/label'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert those values into `XPath` expression as below:

```
packages= ["EVENINGS_AND_WEEKEND_EXTRA", "ANYTIME_EXTRA"]

for i in packages:
    name= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productButtonControls_ST_%s"]/label' % i)
    print name.text
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! It was so simple, i really need to brush up my basics..;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the find_element_by_xpath -> find_elements_by_xpath